Multi-chain Safe infrastructure setup cannot view safe (Safe gets deployed but not picked up by the UI)
http://localhost:8000/cgw/v1/chains/1511670449/safes/0x49338d238F9B98fab18De689f1435f008a1582F7
Returns me the error {"code":404,"message":"An error occurred"}
I've set up 2 chains in my safe infrastructure (a testnet and a mainnet), I believe something is wrong with the configuration of the transaction service. The steps I did for setting up the second chain (the mainnet) are:

Created a new RPC_NODE_URL_MAINNET in the .env inside root directory
Duplicated txs.env as txs-mainnet.env inside /container-env-files and replaced only the following variables to these values

DATABASE_URL=psql://postgres:postgres@txs-db-mainnet:5432/postgres
REDIS_URL=redis://txs-redis-mainnet:6379/0
CELERY_BROKER_URL=amqp://guest:guest@txs-rabbitmq-mainnet/


Updated docker compose to this GitHub gist file (No need to go through the entire file, the things I've added are a separate instance of tx-db and duplicated all the services under Safe transaction service and added volumes on line 3, line 36 and added txs-web-mainnet(the new transaction service as dependency for nginx) on this line)

Added the following to nginx.conf


   upstream txs_app_server_mainnet {
      server unix:/nginx-txs-mainnet/gunicorn.socket fail_timeout=0;
    ...same as txs_app_server
    }

        location /txs-mainnet/static {
            alias /nginx-txs-mainnet/staticfiles;
            expires 365d;
        }

        location /txs-mainnet/ {
            ...Same as /txs/...
            proxy_pass http://txs_app_server_mainnet/;
        }


I think I am doing something wrong in my docker-compose and not the nginx configuration

Did you make sure that:

you deployed all the required contracts on all your custom chains;
you added the custom proxy factory in django;
you have set up a separate txs-db, amqp and celery instance for each chain you want to support?

Please let me know! Thank you in advance 
Best, Louis

Hello, yes I have done all the steps. I've also shared the docker-compose file that I'm using (after adding the separate instance of txs-db and all the services under Transaction service)

Thank you for your answer; unfortunately after checking with the dedicated team, we won't be able to provide support on this scenario as the modifications on the docker-compose are too heavy. We would suggest testing your networks first without any modification, and then try adding other networks progressively. Feel free to ask another question on a specific point of the setup for a single network, if anything is not working well, before expanding with other ones.
